# Issue while passing list using lambda for MVC helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I am developing a MVC helper, in which I want to process each property of Model.

I created following class:

```
public class DataTableHtmlString<T> : HtmlString
    where T : class
{
    public DataTableHtmlString(string value) :
        base(value)
    {
    }

    public DataTableHtmlString<T> Columns<TM>(Expression<Func<TM, T>> columns)
        where TM : DataTableColumn<T>
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

My datacolumn class looks like this:

```
public class DataTableColumn<T>
    {
        internal string ColumnTitle { get; set; }

        public void Column(Expression<Action<T>> column)
        {

        }
    }
```

When I use to call my helper method as:

```
@(Html.MyControls()
                .MyGrid<PersonModel>()
                .Columns(column =>
                {
                    column.Column(w => w.Name);
                })
)
```

It is giving the error for .Columns method as:
"*The type arguments for method 'DataTableHtmlString.Columns(Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*"

**Update**

I added    `Columns<DataTableColumn<Jquery.DataTable.MVC5.Demo.Models.PersonModel>>` and its working but I have already mentioned for Columns method that TM is DataTableColumn and T is class which will be available with `MyGrid<PersonModel>`so why i need to define again? Compiler should know from the signature itself i think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the generic in method `Columns<TM>()` you probably want to replace the TM generic with `DataTableColumn<something>` or `DataTableColumn<PersonModel>`:

```
Html.MyControls()
    .MyGrid<PersonModel>()
    .Columns<DataTableColumn<PersonModel>>(column =>
    {
        column.Column(w => w.Name);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you @AxelWass for reply. This work but why I need to do this. I have updated the post. Can you look into it?

Comment: This is because TM cannot be inferred from `column =>{ column.Column(w => w.Name); }`, because here `column` can't be inferred. You can't infer a class by the method you call on that class, because there could be other classes with the same method name. So automatic inference can't be applied, the compiler needs a little help in knowing what the `column` parameter is, and what class TM represents.

Comment: [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-method-groups/) you can see some more information about C# type inference, its a little bit outdated, but I think it could yelp you anyway.